# Advice on cleaning/tweaking up my HTML + CSS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Very new am I to HTML + CSS, and with being very new comes very challenging tasks that I bring upon myself. I have a website that I am trying to make for myself; here's what it looks like:

[TOP OF WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zelss.jpg)

[BOTTOM OF WEBSITE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecwII.jpg)

Now, externally it looks great and mostly everything lines up. Now, I know for a FACT that my coding is horrendous, disgraceful, horrifying and the like. I've been trying to teach myself to code but I can't quite grasp what I am doing wrong, and so I hope that I can find advice here.

Disclaimer: Viewers can peak at their own discretion. The following code may kill you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Andre Tiglao</title>
<link href="./css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/actor:n4:default;alfa-slab-one:n4:default;advent-pro:n4,n7:default;source-sans-pro:n4,n2:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Andre Tiglao</a></div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navlist">
        <li class="navlistitem active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
        <li class="navlistitem"><a href="#">About</a> </li>
        <li class="navlistitem"><a href="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/andre/Desktop/Website Tutorials/Exercise Files/Chapter 05/04/04 Final/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a> </li>
        <li class="navlistitem"><a href="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/andre/Desktop/Website Tutorials/Exercise Files/Chapter 05/04/04 Final/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<img src="./images/gadgets.jpg" class="img-responsive image" alt="Placeholder image">
<div class="container1">
<img class="img-responsive image2" src="images/portrait.jpg" alt="" />
<section class="sectionRight">
  <h2>About Me</h2>
  <p>I've been working with computers for most of my life, and have been learning many things along the way. I remember starting with an old, vile Dell laptop when I was a kid, and did the usual things like browsing the web and playing video games. As a grew up, so did my technology. I eventually picked up video editting in iMovie, then went to Final Cut Pro to make myself look cooler. But, it was also about the capabilities as well. I then switched to Adobe and started using Premiere Pro and Photoshop. From that point on, I've been exploring all of the different themes, styles, and techniques to make myself a unique artist. I try to make my artwork meaningful with depth and certain elements that make the art piece stick out. I bear the mindset of never giving up, always finding a way to make something workout. Most of my projects bring me to obstacles that make it hard to continue, and I can find myself staring at the screen for minutes, if not hours. For me, design consists of the Brainstorming, the Rough Draft, and the part where you have to hand it in for a deadline.</p>
</section>
</div>
<footer>Copyright 2017. JT Tiglao <a href="#">website</a></footer>
<script src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/andre/Desktop/Website Tutorials/Exercise Files/Chapter 05/04/04 Final/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/andre/Desktop/Website Tutorials/Exercise Files/Chapter 05/04/04 Final/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
 background-color: #A9A9A9;
 background-attachment: scroll;
 font-family: source-sans-pro;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 200;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
h1 {
 font-family: advent-pro;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1em;
 height: 1em;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 text-shadow: 4px 5px 17px #000000;
}
h2 {
 font-family: alfa-slab-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 140%;
 text-align: center;
}
footer {
 font-size: small;
 text-align: center;
 clear: both;
 position: static;
 left: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

 


.asideLeft {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 background-size: 152% auto;
 background-position: 36% 0%;
 padding-bottom: 192px;
 padding-top: 192px;
}
.sectionRight {
 float: right;
 padding-top: 0;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 2.5%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 50%;
 height: 85vh;
 padding-right: 1%;
}
.container1 .sectionRight p {
 font-size: 87%;
 margin-top: -2%;
}
header {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 70px;
 padding-right: 0px;
}
nav {
 background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.navlist {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.navlistitem {
}
.navlistitem a {
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 padding-top: 14px;
 padding-left: 16px;
 padding-right: 16px;
 padding-bottom: 16px;
 color: #6B6B6B;
}
.navlistitem a:hover {
 color: black;
 background-color: #358B6C;
}
.container-fluid .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
 font-family: alfa-slab-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 color: #00CC24;
}
.image {
 margin-top: -30px;
 padding-top: 0px;
}
.image2 {
 float: left;
 max-width: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 85vh;
 width: 50%;
}
.container1 {
 -o-object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 650px){
.asideLeft {
 width: 90%;
 float: none;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.sectionRight {
 width: 90%;
 float: none;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-top: 30px;
 margin-left: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
body {
 background-color:darkslategray;
 background-image: url();
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 font-family: actor;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
h1 {
 font-family: alfa-slab-one;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 1em;
 height: 1em;
}
header {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
p {
 font-size: large;
}
}

@media (max-width: 700px){
.image {
 margin-top: -10px;
}
}
```

I think most of my wrong-doings come in the CSS code.
Have mercy on me... it's my first time!

Thanks so much for attempting to help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Hmmm i don't see anything "horrifying" here. When i started out i used to write inline CSS, mixed with HTML attributes for styling. At least you have enough knowledge to separate presentation from Design. Your CSS could be better but it's not horrifying

Comment: Though i don't really think this question is ontopic here. Since your code works and you're looking for advice on how to improve it

Comment: Belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is quite off topic here :(